# Declaring global variable inside MySQL query nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm trying to declare a variable inside a connection query to get it to work.

```
var chk = cont.query("SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE name = '"+ usr +"'", function(rows) {
    var row = rows;
    res.send(row);
});

console.log(row[0].amount);
```

It returns this error: `ReferenceError: row is not defined`

How can I do this successfully.

Comment: If you declare the variable inside the function, don't expect it to be visible outside, in the console.log() call...

Comment: Is there a way though to get it out of the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
var chk = cont.query("SELECT * FROM `points` WHERE name = '"+ usr +"'", function(rows) {
  var row = rows;
  console.log(row[0].amount)
  res.send(row);
});
```

You can't access `row` variable outside the function where it is declared. And even if you declared `row` globally (outside the callback) it wouldn't work as the code you posted is executed asynchronously. Query callback function is executed after `console.log(row[0].amount);` from your code thus you wouldn't have rows reference anyway.

Obviously if the code snippet you posted is your full code there is no need to declare `row` variable at all.

Comment: So there is no possible way of getting this outside the query?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do, if you want to reference rows somewhere else you will have to used either your own callback and pass rows there, implement above as Promise which is returning rows and process it further once you actually have the data or have a look at async module which handles situations where further logic is dependent on a callback result

Comment: I would like to use the `rows` data outside the that query.